# How to create thumbnail of .doc file using php?

Tags: javascript, php, ms-word

I want to display thumbnail of .doc file. Means I want to show the first page of the .doc file as thumbnail image using php. Like first page of pdf is changing to
image using imagic extension.

Comment: and what have you **tried yourself** so far?

Comment: i tried with imagick php extension but it support pdf only

Comment: And what have you tried to produce a thumbnail for .doc files?

Comment: i tried imagick

Comment: How is this problem related to Javascript?